# Xamarin iOS UITableView Calls Delegate Methods For ALL Cells on Initial Setup, Not Just Visible Ones

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a `UITableView` with custom cells. This TableView is in a View Controller, and takes up the full dimensions of the View. The `RowHeight` of each cell is set to the height of the TableView, so each cell takes up the full screen (less the navbar). Here's a screenshot of what that setup looks like. `Red` is my custom cell; swiping down would page to the next one, which is of a different color:

[image: UITableView Cell]

When the TableView first becomes visible on screen I pass the model (a collection of colors) through to a `Setup` method, which then sets up the `Delegates`. During this initial setup, the `GetCell` method of the `UITableViewDataSource` delegate is called for *every* cell, despite only one cell being visible at a time. This then triggers the `WillDisplay` and `CellDisplayingEnded` delegate methods of the `UITableViewDelegate` class.

I was under the impression that `UITableView` will only create an instance of each cell as needed (when becoming visible), but it appears to be creating an instance for every cell on load, regardless of visibility.

I created a slimmed down sample to share which has 6 total records for the table. I then added a log to the beginning of each of the aforementioned delegate methods, here's the output when the TableView is setup:

```
[0:] GetCell called. Row 0
[0:] WillDisplayCell called. Row 0, RowHeight 672
[0:] GetCell called. Row 1
[0:] WillDisplayCell called. Row 1, RowHeight 672
[0:] GetCell called. Row 2
[0:] WillDisplayCell called. Row 2, RowHeight 672
[0:] GetCell called. Row 3
[0:] WillDisplayCell called. Row 3, RowHeight 672
[0:] GetCell called. Row 4
[0:] WillDisplayCell called. Row 4, RowHeight 672
[0:] GetCell called. Row 5
[0:] WillDisplayCell called. Row 5, RowHeight 672
[0:] CellDisplayingEnded called. Row 1, RowHeight: 672
[0:] CellDisplayingEnded called. Row 2, RowHeight: 672
[0:] CellDisplayingEnded called. Row 3, RowHeight: 672
[0:] CellDisplayingEnded called. Row 4, RowHeight: 672
[0:] CellDisplayingEnded called. Row 5, RowHeight: 672
```

As mentioned before, only one cell is visible on screen at a time. Why do all 6 cells get created initially?

**Sample Code**

```
public class SampleCell : UITableViewCell {
    public void Setup(UIColor color) {
        BackgroundColor = color;
    }
}

public class SampleTableViewDataSourceDelegate : UITableViewDataSource {
    public SampleTableViewDataSourceDelegate(UIColor[] model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    private readonly UIColor[] model;

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) {
        Debug.WriteLine($"GetCell called. Row {indexPath.Row}");
        var reuseIdentifier = "SampleCell";

        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(reuseIdentifier) as SampleCell;

        cell = (cell ?? (cell = new SampleCell()));

        cell.Setup(model[indexPath.Row]);

        return cell;
    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView) {
        return 1;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableView, nint section) {
        return model.Length;
    }
}

public class SampleTableViewDelegate : UITableViewDelegate {
    public SampleTableViewDelegate(UIColor[] model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    private readonly UIColor[] model;

    public override void WillDisplay(UITableView tableView, UITableViewCell cell, NSIndexPath indexPath) {
        Debug.WriteLine($"WillDisplayCell called. Row {indexPath.Row}, RowHeight {tableView.RowHeight}");
    }

    public override void CellDisplayingEnded(UITableView tableView, UITableViewCell cell, NSIndexPath indexPath) {
        Debug.WriteLine($"CellDisplayingEnded called. Row {indexPath.Row}, RowHeight: {tableView.RowHeight}");
    }
}

public partial class SampleTableView : TableViewBase {
    public SampleTableView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) {
        PagingEnabled = true;
    }

    private UIColor[] model;

    public void Setup(UIColor[] model) {
        this.model = model;

        Delegate = new SampleTableViewDelegate(model);
        DataSource = new SampleTableViewDataSourceDelegate(model);
    }
}
```

Then, in my `ViewController`, I pass the model through as follows:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad() {
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    var model = new UIColor[] {
        UIColor.Green,
        UIColor.Red,
        UIColor.Magenta,
        UIColor.Cyan,
        UIColor.Blue,
        UIColor.Purple
    };

    SampleTableView.RowHeight = SampleTableView.Frame.Height;
    SampleTableView.Setup(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh lawd, the `EstimatedRowHeight` also needed to be set.

`SampleTableView.EstimatedRowHeight = SampleTableView.Frame.Height;`

That fixed my issue. Now `GetCell` is only being called once on load, as there is only one visible cell at a time.

Docs (apple, but the same goes for xamarin):
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614925-estimatedrowheight